# Check if UITextField inside UITableViewCell is empty

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, uitextfield, protocols

I have a custom cell with a `UITextField` as a subview.  I would like to check whether this `UITextField` is empty or not.

Is there a way to do this or would I need to implement a protocol to pass to the ViewController?

### Custom Cell Class

```
class TitleCell: UITableViewCell {

    var titleTextField = UITextField()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        contentView.addSubview(titleTextField)
    }
```

### View Controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let titleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: titleCellIdentifier) as! TitleCell
        let categoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: categoryCellIdentifier)!
        switch createEventSections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row] {

        case .Title:
            return titleCell
        case .Category:
            return categoryCell
    }
}
```

### Update

I've implemented a small protocol to pass a bool value if the titleTextField is empty or not but its still not enabling the barbuttonItem.

### Custom Cell Class

```
protocol TitleTextFieldDelegate {
    func titleTextFieldIsEmpty(isEmpty: Bool)
}

class TitleCell: UITableViewCell {

    var titleTextField = UITextField()
    var titleTextFieldEmpty: Bool = true
    var delegate: TitleTextFieldDelegate?

titleTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(titleTextFielddidChangeInput), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func titleTextFielddidChangeInput(textField: UITextField) {
    if (titleTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
        titleTextFieldEmpty = true
    } else {
        titleTextFieldEmpty = false
    }
}
```

### View Controller

```
titleCell.delegate = self

extension CreateEventController {

    func titleTextFieldIsEmpty(isEmpty: Bool) {
        if !isEmpty == true {
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in your `TitleCell` and assign `titleTextField.delegate = self` then access `UITextFieldDelegate` to check if `titleTextField` is empty or not. note it's when your titleTextField update or user enter or delete new values

Comment: @GovindKumawat How do I pass the result to the ViewController? I need to enable a UITabBarItem if the UITextField isn't empty.

Comment: For changing values, state or passing data for your `viewController` you do need to implement a protocol. Check `UITextField` is possible without using protocol.